# install a dimmer to a non dimmable led strip

Tags: led, led-strip, dimmer

I have a led strip installed. the type is 5050 14.4 watts/meter.  I do not know if it is dimmable or not. What happens if i install a dimmer to the strip and it is not dimmable?

Comment: Standard dumb rgb led strips are "dimmable" through the use of a PWM led driver.

Comment: Specifying operating voltage would help immensely. Single color or RGB?

Comment: 12 volts. single color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5050 SMD leds, are plain RGB leds. In these strips you have, they just add some current limiting resistances, one for the red and another for green/blue as they (the strips) operate at higher voltages.
So yes, the dimmer you have is probably a PWM generator. It will work as in any other LED in the world.
The difference would be if your LEDs had an internal PWM generator and accepted a specific protocol. That is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The dimmer will not function properly with DC regardless. You will need to find a specific DC LED dimmer device.

Comment: I am talking about a led dimmer for this job.

Comment: Did you think that might be important to mention?

Comment: yes. you told me to find a specific dimmer so i did. leave the irony aside when you hit the post an answer button!!